# Pythonic way to find the name of global namespace imports

Tags: python, introspection

I am trying to build some dynamic code that parses a text file with objects named from the imports at the top of the module... right now I iterate through all items in `sys._getframe(0)` to find `f_globals`.  Is there a more pythonic way of finding `f_globals`?

```
import re
import sys
import inspect
## Import all Object models below
from Models.Network.Address import MacAddress as _MacAddress
from Models.Network.Address import Ipv4Address as _Ipv4Address

class Objects(object):
    "Define a structure for device configuration objects"

    def __init__(self):
        "Initialize the Objects class, load appropriate objects"
        self.objects = dict()
        for name, members in inspect.getmembers(sys._getframe(0)):
            if name == 'f_globals':
                for modname, ref in members.items():
                    if re.search('^_[A-Za-z]', modname):
                        self.objects[modname] = ref
        return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals)?

Answer (score 1):

Can't You just use

```
globals()
```

?

Moreover, is there a reason why not explicitly specify object to iterate over? That way, you are not prone to "globals" "pollution" by some correlated imports.

Comment: I am renaming all the classes I care about as `_SomeObject`... then a user's config file has to specify that exact object name before use; so I think it's reasonable to use this technique.  Do you have another recommendation?

Comment: @Mike: This is only a matter of taste of course, but I'd probably still use a global dictionary of objects. IMO, explicitly naming which objects are usable by user helps the readability (as well as it avoids globals introspection, but that is minor point) more than magic "_" prefix (used for "internals" by convention, where now it's used as "API marker"). YMMV.